# When are Native VLANs used? Are there times when a Native VLAN will never be used?

Tags: switch, vlan, switchport

This is probably a simple one, but I am very new to VLANs.

I'd like to avoid using VLAN 1 as well as gain a better understanding of when native VLANs come into play when setting up a switch.

On an 8-port switch, if ports 1-4 are set as access ports (untagged) on VLAN 10, and ports 5-7 are set as access ports (untagged) on VLAN 20, if port 8 is set to trunk mode (tagged, to connect to another switch) with native VLAN still on VLAN 1, that native VLAN 1 would never actually be used, right, since all traffic is set to VLAN 10 and 20?  If this is correct, what would the setup look like for traffic to use the native VLAN?

Comment: Is this a Cisco switch?

Comment: I've been using Packet Tracer (Cisco), but also have access to an HP Procurve as well as Netgear managed switch...hence my terminology possibly being messy.

Comment: You can set up Cisco to not trunk VLAN and have all VLANs on a trunk as tagged, so there is no native VLAN. Other vendors  sometime need VLAN 1 as a native VLAN. It depends on the version of STP used.

Comment: I assumed trunk = tagged. So when an untagged frame associated with a VLAN like VLAN 10, that frame would be tagged as 10 on the trunk. Is that not always the case?

Comment: That depends on how it is configured. You could have VLAN 10 as the native VLAN, so it would not be tagged. You can simply leave VLAN 1 as the native (untagged) VLAN, and remove it from from the list of VLANs allowed on the trunk (a Cisco best practice). That may not work on other vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an 8-port switch with ports 1-4 on VLAN 10, and 5-7 on VLAN 20, port 8 as trunk and default VLAN 1 ...

It's correct, VLAN 1 shouldn't be used

Watch for

- Untagged frames arriving on the trunk port 8
- Tagged-as-VLAN-1 frames arriving on the access ports or the trunk port

What happens with these depends on your manufacturer, model, and potentially other configuration.  The normal goal would be to

- Drop any untagged frames arriving on a trunk
- Drop any unknown-VLAN tagged frames arriving anywhere

How you configure this depends on the particular switch.

Of course, if everything is configured correctly, you'll never get these untagged or tagged with unknown VLAN frames.  But what's at the other end of all your wires?  If there is any chance of malicious frames, or the ever-present certainty of configuration errors, this is just for protection. As a security matter, one of the first things the malcious systems do is mess with VLANs and MAC addresses.

Comment: This leads me to another related question, wouldn't any untagged frame arriving on trunk port 8 have to associated with VLAN 10 or 20 since that's how the ports have been setup?

Comment: Assuming you only have 10 and 20 defined: yes, only tagged-10 and tagged-20 arriving on trunk port will be useful.  But you might get malicious or erroneous packets with funny tags or no tag.  All depends on what's on the other end of the trunk.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That makes sense.